# Android Find out what view is present

Tags: java, android

I have an activity that when created contains an EditText but if you click a button it is replaced with a custom view called a MinPick. I need another class to get the view via findViewById(). But of course I need to define what the variable getting the id should be. Either EditText or MinPick. How do I do some sort of conditional if it is not an EditText it must be a MinPick.

Comment: In such cases I create both views with different IDs and change its visibility. It's much simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "instanceof":

```
final View tempView = findViewById(R.id.XXXxxxxXXX);

if (tempView instanceof EditText)
{
// TODO Do some stuff
}
else
{
// TODO Do some other stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the returned object's class using `instanceof`:

```
final View v = findViewById(R.id.floating_component);
if (v instanceof EditText)
    // do stuff with the EditText instance;
else if (v instanceof MinPick)
    // do stuff with the MinPick instance;
```

On the other hand, `@Sergey Glotov` is right, it's a lot nicer technique to deal with states and based on them show the appropriate view.